# tel: tag in chrome (mac os x) opens facetime, but in gmail it opens hangouts, how to make it open hangouts everywhere?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, html5, telephony

There is a discussion about the handler of the tel tag here: 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/ItliGvezjdM

However, no solution was proposed to make hangouts handle all such tags.

I looked into the chrome protocol handler settings and could not find such a setting. I also attempted to reverse engineer the gmail source code to find out why tel tag is taking me to the hangouts, but I got nowhere. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm close, but could use some help. I have this bash script that I used on linux to open hangouts with `tel:` links:

```
#!/bin/bash

number=${1//tel:/}
open "https://hangouts.google.com/?action=chat&pn=$number"
```

Then I found that I can create an app using the built-in `Automator` application that will run the bash script, and save it as an app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/281455/817950

Next, I used [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) (freeware) to change the default app to this Hangouts Call app I made.

Now, whenever I click a `tel:` link it opens hangouts, but the issue is the arguments aren't getting passed in. If anyone can figure out how to get the args passed in to the app and pass them along to the bash script, that would be awesome.